# Keyboard shortcut for Service in OS X doesn't work outside of application focus

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, services, automator, macos-catalina

I have created a service for music application for next and previous track buttons on my keyboard.

[image]

[image]

Problem is when i click on music application and press the keyboard shortcut it works, but when I click out of music app, `focus out` service won't work.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I made a solution to make global media keys using automator

First you need to create quick action service for each shortcut you need, for example for next track music I created this quick action service :

[image]

Then you need to create automator application(AppleScript) to do the job :

[image]

Finally you need to define keyboard shortcuts for actions you created:
[image]

Now close the windows and enjoy your new functional keys.
There should be better solution that creating single application for each task, like sending parameter to single application to do all the actions. I'll update my answer if I could accomplish that.